# IE 9 :: Display XML code into a Div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-9

I've been trying to display my XML code into a Div with Javascript but in the Internet Explorer won't work as follows:

```js
$('footer #xml_content').val($parsed.find('poem').html());
$('div#explanation').html($parsed.find('explanation').html());
```

Although it does works with the functions below as `text()` but the XML tags won't display:

```js
$('footer #xml_content').html($parsed.find('poem').text());
$('div#explanation').html($parsed.find('explanation').text());
```

Can anyone can figure out this puzzle?
Thank you!

```js
function go_poem(pnum, poem, live, id_timer1, id_timer2, reset) { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: _list_poems[ parseInt(pnum)-1 ], 
        dataType: "xml", 
        success: function (xml) { 
            var $parsed = $(xml); 
            var $texto = $parsed.find("texto"); 
            $('footer #xml_content').html(
                document.createTextNode( $('poem').html() )
            );
            $('div#explanation').html(
                document.createTextNode( $('explanation').html() )
            );
/* Remainder of code not included */
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape all `<>` with `&lt;` or `&gt;` if you actually want to display those tags as text.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

After speaking with the OP in a chat, we settled on the following pattern:

```js
var box = $("<div></div>");

$("footer #xml_content").html(function () {
    box.html( $parsed.find("poema").clone() );
    return box.html();
});
```

Due to *permission* restrictions we had to add the XML node to a temporary node and then return the html of the temporary, unattached, node.

**Original Answer**

Create a `textNode` from the XML:

```js
document.createTextNode( $parsed.find('poem').html() );
```

Note however that your markup *may* not be exactly what you wrote to begin with. I've created a small fiddle to demonstrate this approach, as well as included some invalid markup at the end for demonstration purposes.

The browser is will attempt to repair/re-arrange elements and attributes. As a result, what you retrieve from `$.fn.html` may not reflect what was given to the parser to begin with.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/zvxj3yh4/

Comment: Thank you. It outputs "undefined" in divs? Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: @Hyperion Please share your code. You should not be seeing `undefined` unless you have a bad reference somewhere.

Comment: Did you create tags called "poema" and "explicacao"? Or are these supposed to be ID/class names?

Comment: I did. I just translated them here initially to make more sense, since they are portuguese. I'm sorry.

Comment: So you have `<poema>Texto aqui</poema>`? Are these inside the original document, or part of `$parsed`? If they're inside `$parsed` you need to find them there: `$parsed.find("poema").html()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65107/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-hyperion).